# How to stop a websocket client without stopping reactor

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I have an app similar to a chat-room writing in python that intends to do the following things:

1. A prompt for user to input websocket server address.
2. Then create a websocket client that connects to server and send/receive messages. Disable the ability to create a websocket client.
3. After receiving "close" from server (NOT a close frame), client should drop connecting and re-enable the app to create a client. Go back to 1.
4. If user exits the app, it exit the websocket client if there is one running.

My approach for this is using a main thread to deal with user input. When user hits enter, a thread is created for WebSocketClient using AutoBahn's twisted module and pass a Queue to it. Check if the reactor is running or not and start it if it's not. 
Overwrite on message method to put a closing flag into the Queue when getting "close". The main thread will be busy checking the Queue until receiving the flag and go back to start. The code looks like following.

Main thread.

```
def main_thread():
    while True:
        text = raw_input("Input server url or exit")
        if text == "exit":
            if myreactor:
                myreactor.stop()
            break
        msgq = Queue.Queue()
        threading.Thread(target=wsthread, args=(text, msgq)).start()

        is_close = False
        while True:
            if msgq.empty() is False:
                msg = msgq.get()
                if msg == "close":
                    is_close = True
                else:
                    print msg
                if is_close:
                    break
        print 'Websocket client closed!'
```

Factory and Protocol.

```
class MyProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):
    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        msg = payload.decode('utf-8')
        self.Factory.q.put(msg)
        if msg == 'close':
            self.dropConnection(abort=True)

class WebSocketClientFactoryWithQ(WebSocketClientFactory):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queue = kwargs.pop('queue', None)
        WebSocketClientFactory.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Client thread.

```
def wsthread(url, q):
    factory = WebSocketClientFactoryWithQ(url=url, queue=q)
    factory.protocol = MyProtocol
    connectWS(Factory)
    if myreactor is None:
        myreactor = reactor
        reactor.run()
    print 'Done'
```

Now I got a problem. It seems that my client thread never stops. Even if I receive "close", it seems still running and every time I try to recreate a new client, it creates a new thread. I understand the first thread won't stop since `reactor.run()` will run forever, but from the 2nd thread and on, it should be non-blocking since I'm not starting it anymore. How can I change that?

**EDIT:**

I end up solving it with

1. Adding `stopFactory()` after disconnect.
2. Make protocol functions with `reactor.callFromThread()`.
3. Start the reactor in the first thread and put clients in other threads and use `reactor.callInThread()` to create them.

Comment: Server can close client socket, did you want handle all client errors on server ?

Comment: @dsgdfg The fact is I'm trying to duplicate an existing app but I don't own the client or the server so I don't have the code. From what I know using wireshark, I can see server sends message "close" and client reply a close frame with code 1001 and just exit. I want to do the same but I don't know how to close the client and let the thread return so I can do other jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main_thread` creates new threads running `wsthread`.  `wsthread` uses Twisted APIs.  The *first* `wsthread` becomes the reactor thread.  All subsequent threads are different and it is undefined what happens if you use a Twisted API from them.

You should almost certainly remove the use of threads from your application.  For dealing with console input in a Twisted-based application, take a look at `twisted.conch.stdio` (not the best documented part of Twisted, alas, but just what you want).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I think that might be the issue. I understand that using a single thread might fit Twisted better, but I need to do something -> start websocket client -> do something based on result, repeat. As far as I know, I need to do reactor.run() to start the websocket client, but it will block forever. Is there a better way to do above without using thread? I also have a GUI thread which I don't know if it's good to go without multithreading.

Comment: Twisted has various bits of GUI integration.  Depending on which toolkit, you may be able to find a way to run a GUI and Twisted in a single thread.  Also, if you're familiar with GUI programming (without extra threads, anyway) then a lot of those ideas also apply to Twisted.  For example, you don't write a `while True:` loop in Tkinter... you use the `after_idle` API.  Likewise, Twisted has APIs to allow you to schedule more code to run later to let you avoid having a loop that blocks the reactor thread (and avoids you being blocked by the fact that `reactor.run` blocks).